# What happened to my legend, some of the natural disaster legend dissapeared?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\number-of-natural-disaster-events.csv')
df.drop(['Code'], axis = 1)
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='Year',columns='Entity',values='Number of reported natural disasters (reported disasters)')
df_pivot = df_pivot.drop(['Impact'],axis=1)
df_pivot = df_pivot.fillna(0)
df_pivot = df_pivot.reset_index()
df_pivot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=True, sharex=True, figsize=(20, 10))
legend = []
for col in df_pivot.columns:
    if col != "Year":
       sns.regplot(ax=ax,data=df_pivot,x="Year", y=col)
       legend.append(col)
       ax.legend(legend,bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1),fancybox=True,loc='upper center',shadow=True,
                   ncol=2)
```

The CSV file is available [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/dataenergy/eda-of-climate-change-and-natural-disasters/data).

When I try the code, I get a graph like this:

[image: Graph with legend at the bottom]

Why is the legend output wrong? I was trying to make the legend all the natural disaster to its respective colour line, but gives circle instead.
[image: Interestingly, if i changed regplot to lineeplot it will work, so im unsure whats the issue as i really would like to use seaborn.regplot]

Interestingly, if i changed regplot to lineeplot it will work, so im unsure whats the issue as i really would like to use seaborn.regplot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You have already shared the code, so it would help us if you could share the data as well that is required to plot the figure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @medium-dimensional is this source better?, i have spent hours trying to debug but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the problem. **What is wrong with the image**? What should it show differently, or show that it leaves out, or leave out that it shows? "I was trying to make the legend all the natural disaster to its respective colour line, but gives circle instead." Basically, I can't make any sense out of that sentence.

Comment: Also: please read [ask] and note that this is **not a discussion forum**. We want questions to be [direct and to the point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721). For the code, do not put single backticks around a multi-line code block; use three backticks **on lines by themselves** before and after, **or** four spaces of additional indentation on each line (as you already have). Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for details.

Comment: I edited the question to show proper style and inline the image; however, I need your help to reword the one sentence I asked about, because I really have no idea what it should say instead.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hi, the problem is not the graph itself but the legend, as the different disasters are all diff variables, they used be all different colour key right, but somehow the code gave a circle mark which is not supposed to even happen, the legend should be clean and simple with *all colour lines* for diffferent disaster, and even worse is that the circle refers to the same one as the other variable, and some of the variables do niot even have the legend colour itself in the legend box.

Comment: Im not sure if there is something wrong with my code or with regplot itself cuz the interesting thing is taht if i changed the regplot to a lineplot it would work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

if you get line color from sns and add it to legend with Line2D it will work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\number-of-natural-disaster-events.csv')
df.drop(['Code'], axis = 1)
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='Year',columns='Entity',values='Number of reported natural disasters (reported disasters)')
df_pivot = df_pivot.drop(['Impact'],axis=1)
df_pivot = df_pivot.fillna(0)
df_pivot = df_pivot.reset_index()
df_pivot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=True, sharex=True, figsize=(20, 10))
legend = []
for col in df_pivot.columns:
    if col != "Year":
        sns_ax = sns.regplot(ax=ax,data=df_pivot,x="Year", y=col)
        color = sns_ax.lines[-1].get_color()
        line = mlines.Line2D([], [],color = color, linewidth = 7,
                          markersize=15, label=col)
        legend.append(line)

ax.legend(handles=legend,bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1),fancybox=True,loc='upper center',shadow=True,ncol=2)
```

Comment: is it possible to use seaborn original colours insetad of manual?

Comment: Yes, let me edit

Comment: @moblyelliot Okay i did it ,

Answer (score 0):

You could add a label to the line keywords to make the line automatically appear into the legend. The code could also be simplified a little bit without resetting the index and using the index as `x=`.

The following code uses seaborn's flights dataset for easy reproducibility:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('flights')
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='year', columns='month', values='passengers')
df_pivot = df_pivot[['Mar', 'Jun', 'Sep', 'Dec']] # take only 4 months for a simpler example
df_pivot = df_pivot.fillna(0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 7))
for col in df_pivot.columns:
    sns.regplot(ax=ax, data=df_pivot, x=df_pivot.index, y=col, line_kws={'label': col})

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), fancybox=True, loc='upper center', shadow=True, ncol=2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: adding legend to sns.regplot]

If you want both the line and the marker, you can add two labels per `regplot`. With `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` you can fetch all the andles and labels to be put into the legend. And then combine them as tuples.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 7))
for col in df_pivot.columns:
    sns.regplot(ax=ax, data=df_pivot, x=df_pivot.index, y=col, label=col, line_kws={'label': col})
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=[(h1, h2) for h1, h2 in zip(handles[::2], handles[1::2])],
          labels=labels[::2],
          bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), fancybox=True, loc='upper center', shadow=True, ncol=2)
```

[image: lines and markers for sns.regplot legend]